How to create your own personal macro tab?
I have seen Macro templates created by the developer team that i work with and tried my hand at making my own tab. The main issue i have is that the new tab doesnt allow me to rename it and i cannot make the buttons larger.
i have been looking up a file: officecustomuieditorfiles that was mentioned once. when i  looked it up. i was directed to this site.
https://bettersolutions.com/vba/ribbon/custom-ui-editor.htm
and this download info directed after it says that windows 11 is no longer supporting it.
since im not allowed to download extra software at work:
Does anyone know how to create a new Custom macro tab that i can Rename & have the macro buttons be larger?
Any information or even points into a direction i can go would be much apprecaited.
aldo - here is a copy of my version that i was able to create:
http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=427
    Private Const COMMANDBAR_NAME As String = "Menu"
    Private Const BUTTON_CAPTION As String = "Macros" ' Open
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.commandbarcontrols.add
    'https://bettersolutions.com/vba/enumerations/msocontroltype.htm
    'https://github.com/areed1192/sigma_coding_youtube/blob/master/vba/vba-advanced/commandbar-object/CommandbarControls%20Object.bas
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61918089/adding-macro-to-add-ins-tab-custom-toolbars
'franken start
    Dim objCommandBar As CommandBar
    Dim objButton As CommandBarButton
    ' Try to get the Commandbar (if it exists)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objCommandBar = Me.CommandBars(COMMANDBAR_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    
     If (objCommandBar Is Nothing) Then
        ' Create the commandbar
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objCommandBar = Application.CommandBars.Add(Name:=COMMANDBAR_NAME, Position:=msoBarTop, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
        On Error GoTo 0
        'msoBarTypeNormal
           'msoBarTypeMenuBar
        'msoBarTypePopup
            'msoBarTop
        'msoBarPopup
        ' Valid commandbar?
        
        If (Not objCommandBar Is Nothing) Then
            ' Add the buttons to the command bar
            With objCommandBar
       
       
            
                ' Add button
                Set objButton = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
                 ' Set the button properties
                With objButton
                    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = "Clear"
                    .FaceId = 456
                    .TooltipText = "Clear"
                    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Clear"
                    .Height = 100
                     .Width = 100
                End With
          
                Set objButton = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
                With objButton
                    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = "Combine_DF"
                    .FaceId = 1774
                    .TooltipText = "Combine_DF_Reports"
                    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Combine_DF_Reports"
                    .Height = 100
                     .Width = 100

                End With
               Set objButton = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
              With objButton
                    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = "Inbound_Reports"
                    .FaceId = 526
                    .TooltipText = "Combine_Inbound_Reports"
                    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Combine_Inbound_Reports"
                    .Height = 100
                    .Width = 100

                End With
                Set objButton = objCommandBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Temporary:=True)
                With objButton
                    .Style = msoButtonIconAndCaption
                    .Caption = "Production"
                    .FaceId = 747
                    .TooltipText = "Tester Move_Production"
                    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!Move_Production"
                    .Height = 100
                     .Width = 100
                
                    
                End With
        With Application
        .ShowToolTips = True
        .LargeButtons = True
        .ColorButtons = True
        '.Caption = "&Menu" 'names the menu item
         End With
                
                ' Show the command bar
                .Position = msoBarTop
                .RowIndex = msoBarRowLast
                .Visible = True
    
                
    MsgBox ("Macro's are located on the Add-In's menu tab")
                
            End With
        End If
    End If
    
    

    
End Sub
 
 
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next 'in case the menu item has already been deleted
    Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls("My Macros").Delete 'delete the menu item
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to remove the iTrade command bar
    Call Application.CommandBars(COMMANDBAR_NAME).Delete
    
    ' Restore error handling
    On Error GoTo 0
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to remove the iTrade command bar
    Call Application.CommandBars(Menu).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' Restore error handling
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Try to remove the iTrade command bar
    Call Application.CommandBars(TMenu).Delete
    
    ' Restore error handling
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub

